# beautiful soup problem with extracting text from "a"' tag that includes other tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the "climate 8/17/2019 2:00 PM" from the HTML 'a' tag shown below. 
I wrote code that I thought will extract all the text from the 'a' tag and later on, I will extract the desired sub-string using string operations.

```
<div class="topic">
    <a class="class_a" href="/href_1" data1="" data2="hello" data3="Hi" date="Monday, August 17" time="2:00 PM" topic="climate 8/17/2019 2:00 PM">
            <span>2:00 PM</span>
        <i class="Afternoon"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I run the code below and the result was:

```
2:00 PM
```

I also changed the lines as shown below and it did not help. 
         `bar = topics.find('a')`
         to 
         `bar = topics.find('a', {"class": "class_a"})`

I checked the type of the bar variable is class `bs4.element.Tag` (not a string)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://tbd.com')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

topics = bs.findAll("div", {"class": "topic"})
for topic in topics:
    bar = topic.find('a')
    print (bar.text)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know the class of the element you want to extract the text from, then you can get the value from its properties like any python dict:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<div class="topic">
    <a class="class_a" href="/href_1" data1="" data2="hello" data3="Hi" date="Monday, August 17" time="2:00 PM" topic="climate 8/17/2019 2:00 PM">
            <span>2:00 PM</span>
        <i class="Afternoon"></i>
    </a>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "lxml")
obj = soup.find('a', class_ = "class_a")

print(obj.get('topic'))
#climate 8/17/2019 2:00 PM
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The parser that i am using is an html parser. Your proposed solution is using the lxml parser. Will your solution work with the HTML parser?

Comment: Yes it will. `soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")`

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract the value of the `topic` attribute so you should access it as a key from a dict:

```
print(bar['topic'])
```

Comment: That will give you a `KeyError` if the anchor does not contain `topic`.  Best to use `.get('topic')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the value of the attribute topic instead of the anchor text like below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://tbd.com')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

topics = bs.findAll("div", {"class": "topic"})
for topic in topics:
    bar = topic.find('a')
    print (bar.get('topic'))
```

Comment: Also instead of bar = topics.find('a') it should be bar = topic.find('a')

Answer (score 1):

I think your primary issue you is that you specified the "topics" (plural) inside your loop, but wanted "topic" (singular).

```
# python3 bs_test.py

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# html = urlopen('https://tbd.com')
html = """
<div class="topic">
    <a class="class_a" href="/href_1" data1="" data2="hello" data3="Hi" date="Monday, August 17" time="2:00 PM" topic="climate 8/17/2019 2:00 PM">
            <span>2:00 PM</span>
        <i class="Afternoon"></i>
    </a>
</div>
"""


# bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

topics = bs.findAll("div", {"class": "topic"})
for topic in topics:
    bar = topic.find('a')
    print (bar['topic'])
```